# Is DllImport(..., PreserveSig=false) known to work in Mono?

Tags: c#, .net, mono, dllimport

Is DllImport(..., PreserveSig=false) attribute known to work in **Mono**?

I have an exported dll function declared like this in C:

```
HRESULT MyFunction(INTPTR* psomehandle);
```

And on the C# side I declare it like this:

```
[DllImport("MyDll", PreserveSig=false)]
IntPtr MyFunction();
```

This works as expected in MS.NET, but crashes in Mono because 'psomehandle' is passed as NULL.

---

The following declaration does not cause a crash, but no exception is thrown if E_FAIL it returned from MyFunction.

```
[DllImport("MyDll", PreserveSig=false)]
void MyFunction(out IntPtr somehandle);
```

I've tried this with both Mono 2.6.7 and 2.10.9 on Windows.